# Stop RingCentral softphone from auto dialing call when using RingCentral URI rcmobile

Tags: vb.net, winforms, url-scheme, ringcentral

I have a WinForms app in which I need to allow the user to click a phone icon and have the RingCentral softphone app open with the number in question auto populated.  I have done this successfully, however, it autodials the number every time.  The users do NOT want the RingCentral Phone desktop app to auto dial.  Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The following URI Scheme will open the dialer and pre-fill the number but not dial:

`rcmobile://dialer?number=<phone number>`

For reference, the URI Scheme for launching the app and dialing is:

`rcmobile://call?number=<phone number>`

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The dialer format opens the dialer but doesn't actually populate the "To" box with the number. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/naufrhps/2/